# How do I programmatically access the Settings.bundle?

Tags: swift2, settings.bundle

**Scenario:** 
Settings.bundle within the host application.
[image]

**Goal:** 
To access the data within the settings.bundle.

**Modus Operandi:** 
To dump the settings data into a dictionary for in-program access.

Here's my first attempt.  I tried accessing the path, then the bundle.  Both didn't work:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "bundle")

let myBundle = NSBundle(path: path!)

let myData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path!)
```

What's the correct syntax of collecting data from the Settings.bundle (which contains the root.plist)?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the saved values via `NSUserDefaults`.

For example if you want to get the previously set value (`"bar"`) from the setting named as "foo", then the code to get it is:

`let valueOfFoo = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("foo")`

In this case the content of `valueOfFoo` variable will be `"bar"`.

*Note: this returns an Optional*